# MARS with exceptions.s from SPIM: Symbol "main "not found in symbol table. How can I fix this?

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I just recently downloaded MARS MIPS on my mac again and tried to re-learn how to program. I wrote this code:

```
.data
    myMessage: .asciiz "Hello World \n"
.text
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, myMessage
    syscall
```

When I tried to run it, it gave me this message on a separate exceptions.s tab:

```
Error in /Users/myname/Desktop/exceptions.s line 180 column 6: Symbol "main" not found in symbol table.
```

And this was the portion of the exceptions.s code [from SPIM](https://github.com/TryItOnline/spim/blob/master/exceptions.s), which [the MARS manual](https://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/Help/MarsExceptions.html) says should work under MARS.

```
# Standard startup code.  Invoke the routine "main" with arguments:
#   main(argc, argv, envp)
#
.text
.globl __start          #line 173
__start:
    lw $a0 0($sp)       # argc
    addiu $a1 $sp 4     # argv
    addiu $a2 $a1 4     # envp
    sll $v0 $a0 2
    addu $a2 $a2 $v0
    jal main            #line 180
    nop

    li $v0 10
    syscall         # syscall 10 (exit)

    .globl __eoth
__eoth:             #last line 187
```

I want to start using MIPS again. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program must have a global `main` label, which serves as the entry point of your program:

```
.data
# Data goes here

.text
.globl main
main:
# Code goes here
```